# dynamically split table if over a certain amount of lines?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm currently working with very large datasets, and I was wondering if it would be possible to dynamically cut tables upon hitting the edges of a page. I need this for both vertical and horizontal pages.

I'm aware that you can also split tables by inserting 2 lines with tabular, but I need dynamically split in this case. Here's a picture of what I'm looking for. Thanks! [image: I've attached a screenshot here of what it should look like.]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific stuff that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Would the `longtable` package serve your need?  It will handle if rows reach a page break.  However, it will not handle cases where columns fall off the right-hand side of the page.

Comment: @NBur gothca, sorry about that. New to latex. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I've looked into this a bit, but I thought it just handled multi-page tables. I'll do a double-take on the documentation and read again. Thanks!

Comment: What does the rest of the document look like? Your image suggests a twocolumn layout, but what about the other contents of your ocument? Are they also in a twocolumn format or does this just apply to this particular table?

Comment: splitting for width is harder but your image suggests that you are wasting most of the width with very wide columns consisting of mostly white space. If you adjust your headings to not be wider than the data your table would be a lot narrower. longtable will split the table up over multiple pages if you have many rows.